# Android Pay: what should be 3dsEciIndicator value when decrypted Android Pay payment token doesn't provide one in case of Network Token

Tags: android, android-pay

We are trying to integrate Android Pay into our Application, Chase Payment Tech is our Gateway and so we follow Network Tokens as indicated by Android

In case of Master Card and Discover decrypted Android Pay payment token is not providing 3dsEciIndicator value, what we should be the value that we need to use for 3dsEciIndicator when its not provided in the payment token to process the charge?

Comment: I know for Visa we use 07, not sure for MC or Discover